# Can I use a WITH clause inside a CASE statement?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, reporting-services, with-statement

I have an Oracle procedure that uses a case statement, and inside the case is a WITH clause.

This is what it looks like. I've changed the table names and fields for this post.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TST_PROC
(
    o_Cursor            OUT     SYS_REFCURSOR,
    p_My_Var            IN      VARCHAR2
)
AS

  v_My_Var       VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN

    v_My_Var      := p_My_Var;

  CASE v_My_Var
    WHEN '1' 
    THEN
        OPEN o_Cursor FOR

            WITH
              SQ_Query AS
              (
                SELECT * from My_Table1
              )
            SELECT * from My_Table2 t2, 
                          SQ_Query t1
            WHERE t1.id = t2.id;  
    WHEN '2' 
    THEN
        OPEN o_Cursor FOR

            WITH
              SQ_Query AS
              (
                SELECT * from My_Table1
              )
            SELECT * from My_Table2 t2, 
                          SQ_Query t1
            WHERE t1.id = t2.id; 
  END CASE;
END;
/
```

This compiles in Oracle without any issues. But when I refresh the data set in SSRS, Visual Studio complains. I'm wondering if it is because I'm using a WITH clause inside the case statement. I've not done this before so I'm not sure. Does anyone know?

Comment: What complaints does Visual Studio have? What results do you get when you run this procedure directly?

Comment: This procedure CANNOT compile, because you confused `SQL-CASE expressions` with `PL/SQL-CASE STATEMENT`. They are two different things, their syntaxes are similar, but different. Please compile the procedure again, and then run `SHOW ERRORS` and you will see. Tip: use `END;` instead of `END CASE;`, refer to this link: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php

Comment: @ShannonSeverance in Visual Studio, when I click the the refresh button in the Dataset Properties window, I get that Define Query Parameters dialog that opens. It's the one that appears when there is an error somewhere.

Comment: @kordirko, I re-compiled. No error message in oracle. Not sure what you mean by `because you confused SQL-CASE expressions with PL/SQL-CASE STATEMENT`

Comment: I have no issues creating a simple test case using WITH inside a CASE statement.  Perhaps you are not binding the OUT parameter correctly?

Comment: SSRS can't accept a cursor especially not as an output parameter. You'll need to wrap a select statement around this somehow. I think your `CASE` statement itself is fine though. You could try declaring the subquery first and then do a single conditional select statement to return your results. Also, if there's any way to avoid cursors, that usually helps simplify things.

Comment: @tbone, thanks for letting me know! Good to hear that the WITH clause can be used in a case. For a while there I was thinking that was the issue. So it sounds like there's some problem in the code that Oracle accepts but SSRS is having an issue with

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work using IF ELSE.

Got the help from here:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2237472?tstart=0